# How to rewrite the following into an EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statement that I would like to convert to use an `EXISTS`. How would this be done?

```
with Sales as (
    select 'Office Supplies' Category , 2014 Year,22593.42 Profit UNION all
    select 'Technology', 2014, 21492.83 UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2014,   5457.73 UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2015,   25099.53  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2015,   33503.87  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2015,   50000.00  UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2016,   35061.23  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2016,   39773.99  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2016,   6959.95
)
select Category, Profit - LAG(Profit) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Year) Diff
FROM Sales where 1=1 qualify Diff < 0
```

In other words, I want the query to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE EXISTS (...)
```

Comment: The `QUALIFY` clause is not standard SQL and not yet featured by MySQL either. So, is this about finding an alternative for that clause in MySQL? That would be easy. But why `EXISTS`? Is your idea to apply `WHERE EXISTS (<the row before with a higher profit>)`? That would make the query more complicated than need be.

Comment: EXISTS is not a substitute for FROM; if you have no FROM, there isn't anything meaningful you can do with EXISTS.  can you maybe explain a little *why* you want to change your statement (and provide a working original sql statement)?

Comment: @ysth sorry yes that was a typo.

Comment: what is tbl and how does it relate to Sales?  again, please explain why you are asking; that might help us figure out what kind of answer you are looking for.  as is, there really isn't enough here to have any idea what you want

Answer (score 0):

If `LAG` exists then you can use a sub-query instead of Teradata's `QUALIFY`.

```
SELECT Category, `Year`, Profit
, PreviousProfit
, (Profit - PreviousProfit) AS Diff
FROM
(
    SELECT Category, `Year`, Profit
    , LAG(Profit) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY `Year`) AS PreviousProfit
    FROM Sales AS sale
) AS sale
WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM Sales AS sale2
       WHERE sale2.Category = sale.Category
         AND sale2.Year = sale.Year - 1
         AND sale2.Profit > sale.Profit
) 
AND PreviousProfit > Profit
```

The `EXISTS` isn't really needed then.